Why does bash not report the line error where one leaves off the " at the end
My question is why bash does not report against line 2 where I left off the trailing " at the end on purpose to see how it reports this back.
I run a bash script and get this error:
./test: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "this is life
echo "now is the time"
echo "have we reached the end"


a \n is a character which can exist in a string; if you type on a terminal echo "blah and then hit ENTER, you can continue with hello" on the second line, and get the output of "blah\nhello" as the output.  What you're expecting seems more limited to me, as it allows free form expression of the code and isn't limited to understanding everything only if its on a single line.  The rules bash ~follows were created in the ~1970 so aren't exactly new.

Thank you for this reply and good explanation.

Because that line doesn't contain an error, as it's perfectly legal to include a newline character in a quoted string.
As a matter of fact any character (but an unescaped ", which marks the start / end of a quoted string) could be included in a quoted string if somehow "put" after a " character; a newline character just happens to be easily typed in (just like, e.g., any "ordinary" alphabetical character), and - notably - is not even the most exotic thing that you could include in a quoted string1.
I suggest you break out of the mindset where a string can contain just letters, numbers and punctuation, as it's not like that at all, and being aware of this helps a lot in using the command line / scripting.
Anyways, more to the point, here's a breakdown of what happens and why you're being notified of an error only on line #4:

Bash parses line #2 up until the " character; it starts intrepreting what follows after as a string, and when it stumbles upon the (as discussed above, legal) newline character, it happily swallows it and starts parsing line #3 as a continuation of the string that so far includes what followed the " character, which includes the newline;
Bash parses line #3 up until the first " character; the first string is now correctly and completely parsed. It then parses the remainder of the line as a (legal) unquoted string until the next " character is found, when the cycle repeats: it stumbles upon the (again, as discussed above, legal) newline character, it happily swallows it and starts parsing line #4 as a continuation of the string that so far includes just the newline;
Again, Bash parses line #4 up until the first " character; the second string is now correctly and completely parsed. It then parses the remainder of the line as a (legal) unquoted string until the next " character is found, when the cycle breaks; it stumbles upon the (again, as discussed above, legal) newline character, it happily swallows it and... there's nothing left to parse / EOF (End-Of-File) has been reached. Since EOF has been reached, the last parsed " most definetly has no matching closing quote - hence the error unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' is thrown



In fact, e.g., any other non-printable character (ASCII range 0-31 - and not just those) could also be included in a string if it was pasted after a `"` character. They're really no different from newlines - they're all non-printable characters - it just so happens that newlines can be simply typed in. Another exception to non-printable characters is the tab character, which, much like the newline character, also can be simply typed in.


Thank you for such a detailed explanation on this.

@MIke You're welcome - I'm glad this clears things up
